# Problem with bash builtin bind and escaping

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, escape-characters, shell-builtin

I'm trying to add a history fuzzyfind hotkey to my bash shell. However, my intended command gets cut in the middle:

```
[april@Capybara-2:~]$ cat ~/.bashrc 
bind "\"\C-r\": \"\$(history | fzf | awk '{\$1=\"\"; print substr(\$0,2)}')\""

[april@Capybara-2:~]$ $(history | fzf | awk '{$1="";
```

(The second line is the result when \C+r is pressed.)
I anticipated that \C+r should be bind to `$(history | fzf | awk '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}')`, but that's not the case. Why?

Comment: One really obvious practical problem here is that many commands (e.g. awk, perl, sed, etc one-liners, commands typed in with a backslash at the end of a line, or if/while/until/for commands entered over multiple lines, etc) often contain newlines, and the `history` built-in doesn't have an option to output the history with NUL separators.  Neither does `fc`.   So `fzf` ends up displaying partial commands, up to the first newline, for you to choose from.

Comment: BTW, ignoring that practical problem, since the purpose of the pipe to awk is to remove the history line number, I'd suggest piping to `sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*//'` instead of awk.

Comment: @cas How can I fix the practical problem?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to fix - `fzf` has a `-read0` option (which is half of the solution) but neither `history` nor `fc` have an option to use NUL as the output separator (and that's the other half).   BTW, I noticed the problem when I ran your `history | fzf | awk ...` pipeline and saw lots of partial awk and perl commands that ended at the first newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quoting hell. You have the command in double quotes, so the `\"\"` becomes `""`, so for Readline, the command looks like:

```
bind "\C-r": "$(history | fzf | awk '{$1 = ""; ....
```

See the problem? The string started at `"$(` is ended by the first double quote in `"";`, I'm not sure how exactly string concatenation works for Readline, but it seems like any non-whitespace characters immediately after the closing quote are appended and everything else discarded.

We can fix the quoting accordingly, by using any of:

```
# Extra backslashes inside double quotes
bind "\"\C-r\": \"\$(history | fzf | awk '{\$1=\\\"\\\"; print substr(\$0,2)}')\""
# Wrap the macro in single quotes instead of double quotes
bind "\"\C-r\": '\$(history | fzf | awk \'{\$1=\"\"; print substr(\$0,2)}\')'"
# Use single quotes for the `bind` command argument instead of double quotes
bind '"\C-r": "$(history | fzf | awk '\''{$1=\"\"; print substr($0,2)}'\'')"'
```

Comment: Sorry for the deleted post. Maybe I didn't type my first attempt correctly (or forgot to restart bash). Your answer is correct.

Comment: BTW why is it directly giving $(history | fzf | awk '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}') instead of the evaluated result?

Comment: @AprilGrimoire you need to either (a) Press enter to ask the shell to evaluate it, so add a `\n` to the macro, or (b) use readline's `shell-expand-line`, which is bound by default to `\M-\C-e`, so add `\e\C-e` to the macro

Comment: \M-\C-e is cumbersome, as it requires three keystrokes for each search. (a) is not ideal either since I want the ability to modify the item after finding it. I ended up using a function to modify READLINE_LINE manually.

Comment: @AprilGrimoire you can just add `\e\C-e` to the macro, e.g. `bind '"\C-r": "$(history | fzf | awk '\''{$1=\"\"; print substr($0,2)}'\'')\e\C-e"'`